# Resizing WooCommerce images

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, size

using WooCommerce I put this snippet in function.php to define the size of images overwriting the panel settings :

```
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
$single = array(
    'width'     => '400',   // px
    'height'    => '300',   // px
    'crop'      => 1        // true
);

$thumbnail = array(
    'width'     => '180',   // px
    'height'    => '135',   // px
    'crop'      => 1        // false
);

        $catalog = array(
        'width'     => '140',   // px
        'height'    => '105',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
);

// Image sizes
update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', $single );         // Single product image
update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', $thumbnail );
update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
```

All works fine but now I'd like to set different image sizes relating to $catalog just in single product page (where there's a widget showing that images).
I've tried with conditional statements, cause I don't want to use css tricks, but without luck.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-generate the thumbnails after changing the size? If no, than try force regenerate thumbnails plugin to re-generate images that will have new sizes. When indicating new size in Wp functions, than it will affect new uploads but you also need to regenerate new sizes for previously uploaded ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answear but it's not a problem of image regeneration ... actually I'm working just with some placeholder. My goal it's to set two or more differents dimensions range for the shop categories images so I could get the appropriate one when I load certain pages.